# Presto: Extract values from a string column, which is similar to map, but not a map

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table:

```
Name  pets
--------------
Andy  {"cat":2, "dog":1, "bird":4 ,xxx}
John  {"dog":3, "cat":1, "bird":{}, uyx}
Mary  {"dog":2, "duck":{}, "cat":1, zzz}
```

The pets column is a map, but the table creator made is a string, with some additional characters there. So I can not use `cast(json_parse(pets) as map(varchar, varchar)) AS m`.

In this case, if I want to find out the value of `"cat"`, how do I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_extract()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_extract#regexp_extract):

```
select t.*,
       regexp_extract(pets, '"cats":([^,]*)', 1)
from t;
```